# Query optimization for matching nodes with equal values

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to collect all nodes that have the same property value

```
MATCH (rhs:DataValue),(lhs:DataValue) WHERE rhs.value = lhs.value RETURN rhs,lhs
```

I have created an index on the property

```
CREATE INDEX ON :DataValue(value)
```

the index is created:

```
Indexes
    ON :DataValue(value)          ONLINE
```

I have only 2570 DataValues.

```
match (n:DataValue) return count(n)
> 2570
```

However, the query takes ages/does not terminate within the timeout of my browser.

This surprises me as I have an index and expected the query to run within `O(n)` with `n` being the amount of nodes.

My train of thought is: If I'd implement it myself I could just match all nodes `O(n)` sort them by value `O(n log n)` and then go through the sorted list and return all sublists that are longer than 1 `O(n)`. Thus, the time I could archive is `O(n log n)`. However, I expect the sorting already being covered by the indexing.

**How am I mistaken and how can I optimize this query?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your complexity is actually O(n^2), since your match creates a cartesian product for rhs and lhs, and then does filtering for every single pairing to see if they are equal. The index doesn't apply in your query at all. You should be able to confirm that by running EXPLAIN or PROFILE on the query.

You'll want to tweak your query a little to get it to O(n). Hopefully in a future neo4j version query planning will be smarter so we don't have to be so explicit.

```
MATCH (lhs:DataValue)
WITH lhs
MATCH (rhs:DataValue)
WHERE rhs.value = lhs.value 
RETURN rhs,lhs
```

Note that your returned values will include opposite pairs ((A, B), (B, A)).

Comment: Even though your query makes perfect sense concerning optimization, there is no difference in the execution time. The original query takes 106 seconds and your query takes 107. Though I am quite certain that the 1 sec difference is rather a measurement error than actual difference.

Comment: I was double-checking this a bit myself, and saw something similar. Either I goofed here, or there's been some improvements in the planner that I missed. I'll look into it when I have some time.

Comment: I have noticed that queries in the browser can tend to slow down based upon the number of output rows, and possibly on writing out properties. You may want to test this, to see if the slowdown is with this, or the matching query itself. Try changing the return to `COUNT(rhs)` and see if that shows any notable difference in execution time.

Comment: I did execute both queries using py2neo and got 106 vs. 107 seconds execution time.

Comment: Strange, that seems like far too long. Are you seeing similar times when you execute the query in the browser? Also, can you add the result of a PROFILE of your query to your description (expanding all nodes in the profile result)?